# MotorControlMsgs/Stiffness baxter

Tags: ros, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried viewing the stiffness parameter for the baxter robot, by executing:

```
rostopic echo /robot/limb/right/stiffness
```

but this just gives me an error:

```
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [MotorControlMsgs/Stiffness]. Are your messages built?
```

I tried searching for this message package, but only thing I'm getting is http://wiki.ros.org/control_msgs which doesn't contain stiffness parameters.

Anyone ever had similar problems or knows how to find MotorControlMsgs?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253160/motorcontrolmsgs/stiffness-baxter/) by [Nemanja](https://answers.ros.org/users/29183/nemanja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you setup your Baxter ROS workspace correctly and `source`d the `setup.bash` after `catkin_make`-ing it?

---

Edit: from reading [How to read /robot/limb/left/command_joint_position?](https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/d/msg/brr-users/RXEEWyupdk0/eTywO1oOS4oJ) and [Collision Detection](https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/forum/#!topic/brr-users/RXEEWyupdk0) over at `brr-users` -- which seeing your posts there you also found -- it would appear that topics carrying messages from the `MotorControlMsgs` package are not meant to be used by end-users. The `MotorControlMsgs` package is therefore not available.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nemanja](https://answers.ros.org/users/29183/nemanja/) on 2017-01-27**:
Yes, all other Messages work correctly.

**Comment by [Nemanja](https://answers.ros.org/users/29183/nemanja/) on 2017-01-27**:
Yes, I just got the answer. Thanks for the help!